# How to pass parameters to Table Valued Function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, user-defined-functions

I want to do something like

```
select * from tvfHello(@param) where @param in (Select ID from Users)
```

Comment: Rajivdas: could you clarify your question a bit more. I am afraid that   each of us interpreted it in different ways

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to use **CROSS APPLY** to achieve this

```
select 
    f.* 
from 
    users u
    cross apply dbo.tvfHello(u.ID) f
```

Comment: I have never used `CROSS APPLY` before, Now I see its advantage, Thank a lot @kristof.

Answer (score 5):

The following works in the AdventureWorks database:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.EmployeeByID(@employeeID int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
(
    SELECT * FROM HumanResources.Employee WHERE EmployeeID = @employeeID
)
GO


DECLARE @employeeId int

set @employeeId=10

select * from 
EmployeeById(@employeeId) 
WHERE @EmployeeId in (SELECT EmployeeId FROM HumanResources.Employee)
```

## EDIT

Based on Kristof expertise I have updated this sample if your trying to get multiple values you could for example do:

```
select * 
from HumanResources.Employee e
CROSS APPLY  EmployeeById(e.EmployeeId)
WHERE e.EmployeeId in (5,6,7,8)
```

Comment: in my case I can only the results for employeeId=10, but not for the other value. Any ideas?

Comment: sounds like your trying to do something more complex then your question indicated. (Which I had a feeling you were). You want to pass in for example all the userId's...one way would be to build a delmited string and then break it down in the function but that defeats the purpose.

Comment: Josh. The example that you gave it is actually the same as calling select * from EmployeeById(10) WHERE 10 in (SELECT EmployeeId FROM HumanResources.Employee). To get results for multiple values of parameter you need to use cross apply (SQLServer2005+)

Comment: That would work if that is in fact his intent. Never used Cross Apply

Answer (score 0):

That looks ok to me, except that you should always prefix your functions with their schema (usually dbo). So the query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tvfHello(@param) WHERE @param IN (SELECT ID FROM Users)
```

Comment: I do not think, that would work. if you do not define the @param you will get: Must declare the scalar variable "@param". error. If you define the @param you will get the results to whatever the @param is assigned to (NULL by default). To get the full set of results you need to use CROSS APPLY

Comment: What are you talking about? I'm simply correcting the query that was offered in the sentence. Rajivdas never stated the intent of his query, so you can't possibly know whether he needs to do a CROSS APPLY or not.

Comment: True, the question is not very clear, I based my answer on comments Rajivdas made to answer by Josh. Look at the comment by NTulip to see how confused some people get. But surely it could have been me who interpreted that wrongly